# PHP include. I can't seems to figure this out

Tags: php, html, css, include

I guess I have put everything in place but it seems to be not working at all.

Here is the index.php. I've included the head part, perhaps it would affect the entire files.:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HOME</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, css3, sliding, box, menu, cube, navigation, 
portfolio, thumbnails"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/art_favicon.png" type="image/x-
icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/body.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/headertop.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url(images/graphy.png);
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }       
    </style>

<?php

include ("headertop.php");

?>    


</head>
<body>

<div id="contents">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the headertop.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, css3, sliding, box, menu, cube, navigation, 
portfolio, thumbnails"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/art_favicon.png" type="image/x-
icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/headertop.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

<header> 

<div id="headertop">
  <div id="adams">
    <p>
  <span style="color: #F60;">A</span>ncajas
  <span style="color: #F60;">D</span>igital
  <span style="color: #F60;">A</span>rts &amp;
  <span style="color: #F60;">M</span>edia
  <span style="color: #F60;">S</span>olutions
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

</header> 

</head>

</html>
```

Thanks guys for the hands!

Comment: So you're including an entire HTML document (`headertop.php`) inside the `<head>` section of another HTML document (`index.php`). What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: How many question marks am I allowed here?

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand what `include` does. Literally everything in the "included" file will be put where you call that function. So in this case, you're putting practically an entire HTML document inside the `<head>` of another.

headertop.php should likely only be:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3" />
<meta name="keywords" content="jquery, css3, sliding, box, menu, cube, navigation, portfolio, thumbnails"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/art_favicon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/headertop.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

And the `<header>` tag does not belong in there at all. That needs to go in the body of your document.

Comment: This one works tooo...more power!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should delete everything outside of `<header>...</header>` from your headertop.php file.  You already define the html and head tags in index.php so you don't need to do it again in headertop.php.  However I'm not sure you really want your header block to be inside the page's head section. Shouldn't it be in body?

Comment: This is super! Thanks for the suggestions man. I'll give you five balls...oopsss can't vote yet. But your wit is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HOME</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, css3, sliding, box, menu, cube, navigation, 
portfolio, thumbnails"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/art_favicon.png" type="image/x-
icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/body.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/headertop.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url(images/graphy.png);
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }       
    </style>

<?php

require_once("headertop.php");

?>    

</head>
<body>

<div id="contents">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

headertop.php

```
<header> 
<div id="headertop">
  <div id="adams">
    <p>
  <span style="color: #F60;">A</span>ncajas
  <span style="color: #F60;">D</span>igital
  <span style="color: #F60;">A</span>rts &amp;
  <span style="color: #F60;">M</span>edia
  <span style="color: #F60;">S</span>olutions
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

You don't need to have two same meta-tags or declared Doctype, head or body tag. And for sure, I suggest to you using `require_once`instead of `include`.

Comment: Yup this works man. Thank you very much. Question - what the difference between the two - "include" and "require_once".

Comment: Both actually do the same thing - adding the specified file, but by different way they handle failures. `require_once` is included in the respective functions to avoid problem with function redefinitions. That's preventing the file been included for evaluation or execution from been added more than once.